# How can I create an instance of a class within another class?

Tags: c++, class, vector, initialization

I have written a class in C++ for 3-dimensional vector algebra which I want to use in another class triangle for defining its vertices. When compiling my class I get "Triangle::vert uses undefined class Vec3".

How would I go about solving this? Googling around it seems like member initializer lists might be the solution, although I can't seem to get it right. Before creating the triangle class I could initalize Vec3 objects and use algebraic functions on them in main, but after creating the Triangle class, I can no longer instantiate a Vec3 object in main. Any help would be really appreciated :)

Below is part of the relevant code:

**Triangle.h**

```
#include "Vec3.h"

class Triangle
{
public:
/*----- Variables -----*/
    Vec3 vert; //Vertices, error occurs here
    unsigned r, g, b; //Color
    
/*----- Constructors -----*/
    Triangle();
};
```

**Triangle.cpp**

```
#include "Triangle.h"

Triangle::Triangle()
{
    vert.x = vert.y = vert.z = 0.0;
    r = g = b = 0;
}
```

**Vec3.h**

```
#include <cmath>

class Vec3
{
public:
    /*----- Variables -----*/
    float x, y, z;

    /*----- Constructors -----*/
    Vec3();
    Vec3(const float a);
    Vec3(const float xx, const float yy, const float zz);
```

**Triangle.cpp**

```
#include "Vec3.h"

/*----- Constructors -----*/
Vec3::Vec3()
{
    Vec3::x = Vec3::y = Vec3::z = 0;
}

Vec3::Vec3(const float a)
{
    Vec3::x = Vec3::y = Vec3::z = a;
}

Vec3::Vec3(const float xx, const float yy, const float zz)
{
    Vec3::x = xx; Vec3::y = yy; Vec3::z = zz;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Vec3.h"
#include "Triangle.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Vec3 v1(-2.0f,3.0f,3.0f); //Error here:
    //Line 7: 1. "v1 uses undefined class Vec3"
    //Line 7: 2. "initializing: cannot convert from initializer list to int"
    Triangle t1(1,2,3);
    std::cout << t1.vert.x << " " << t1.vert.y << " " << t1.vert.z;
    return 0;
```

Please notice that I did not paste all functions as they seem to work fine and the constructors and initialization seems to be the problem.

Comment: Looks like you have a typo, `class Triangle { ... };`. The final semi colon is missing from the code you posted.

Comment: If that isn't the issue, then it would help to say which line of the above code the error applies to.

Comment: What about `Vec3.cpp`, are you defining the constructors?

Comment: We can't see the end of the `Vec3` class to check for semi-colons. Please post self-contained code!

Comment: In fact, I think there is something important that you're not including in your posted code, that is causing the error. Perhaps when you try to whittle your code down to a self-contained example, it will compile. Let us know!

Comment: It seems I missed the semicolon when I submitted to stack overflow, but it is there in the class definition in the IDE. I removed Triangle and rebuilt the program which made build and run without errors. However the problem remains when I bring the Triangle class back. The error occurs in the headerfile a line 7: Vec3 vert;

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems that something was changed on Vec3 since your last successful test on the main.
To make certain that's the case - try to rebuild the project without Triangle and retest Vec3.

For further assistant, upload the code for Vec3.cpp, and the working usage of Vec3 on main.